# Force numeric keyboard on iOS using actionscript 3 (in CS flash 5.5)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, keyboard, numeric

I have a textInput box called systolicInput. To record the users blood pressure.

When the user taps on the textInput the iOS virtual keyboard comes up. But it defaults to alphabetic input.

How can I force it to display the numeric input keyboard?

I am using ActionScript 3.

PS: Thanks for reading this post, and any insight will be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Control of the keyboard type is possible in AIR 3 using the new StageText class. (You will have to manually update the AIR SDK to use it in Flash CS5.5. See http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/908/cpsid_90810.html for instructions.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes, that is the way to go. I have it mostly working now. I am having a little trouble getting the returnKeyLabel correct though.